# Prove there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ divides $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can one prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ divides $n!$

Comment: $n^2=1$??????????

Comment: If you mean $n^2-1$, it suffices for $n+1$ to not be prime nor a perfect square.

Comment: How do you perform the division of a number by a relation?

Comment: apologies, that should have read $n^2+1$ (edited now)

Comment: Why do you think it's true?  There certainly aren't a lot of small examples.

Comment: So you’re looking for values of $n$ that satisfy $\mod(n!, n^2+1)=0$

Comment: In first 100 there are $21, 47, 57, 68, 72, 73, 83$. There are quite a few numbers till 1000 as well.

Comment: @lulu Say $n=p$ is prime. Then either $p^2 + 1$ is prime (in which case we lose), or it's composite (in which case we probably win, since all prime factors are less than $p$, although maybe we're unlucky and some large prime factors close to $p$ repeat). I don't know how to turn this heuristic into an argument, though.

Comment: @hunter  $3^2+1=2\times 5$, so this does not work.  To be sure, I expect that $n^2+1$ frequently factors into small powers of small primes.  But my guess is that it is hard to prove much along those lines.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar 18 works as well.

Comment: @Piyush there is also $18$, $38$, $43$, $70$, and many more.