# Intriguing problem based on number theory.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers n for which $n^3+2n^2+n$ divides $n!$.

**My attempt**

I factored $n^3+2n^2+n$ as $n(n+1)^2$. So I need to prove that $n(n+1)^2$ divides $n!$ for infinitely many values of $n$. I do not know how to proceed beyond this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see why you would be done if you can show there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n + 1$ factors in two ways, that is, as a product $N_1 N_2$ and $M_1 M_2$ where $N_1,N_2,M_1,M_2$ are distinct? Now how would you construct infinitely many such $n$?

Comment: It reminds me on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764655/prove-there-are-infinitely-many-natural-numbers-n-such-that-n21-divides-n). Not every such factorisation works, e.g., for $n=5$ we have that $6$ has two different factorisations, but the divisibility is not true.

Comment: See also [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2008565p14069774), which has this question.

Comment: However, as per my teacher, $n = 104$ does satisfy the divisibilty.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess I should have put the word "nontrivial" in front of factorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to show that if $n\equiv -1\mod 4$ and $n>11$ then $n(n+1)^2$ divides $n!$, indeed, if $n=4k-1$, we can write $n(n+1)^2=16nk^2$.
Now since $4k=n+1$ and $n>11$, we have $k>3$ and so we have $k<2k<3k<n$, and there are some even numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that $0<a_1<k<a_2<2k<a_3<n$.
Now by definition, $a_1\cdot k\cdot a_2\cdot 2k\cdot a_3\cdot n\mid n!$ and since $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are all divisible by $2$, we have $n(n+1)^2=16nk^2\mid n!$ as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If $n+1 =pq=rs$ where $r<p<q<s<n $ then $$n! =1\cdot ... \cdot r\cdot...\cdot p\cdot... \cdot q\cdot ...\cdot s\cdot ...\cdot n =k(rs)(pq) n=k(n+1)^2 n$$

Comment: Thanks. So this implies that no $n$ such that $n+1$ is a prime number would satisfy the divisibility? Also how can you prove that there are infinitely many such $n$.

Comment: @Krish The proof by itself does not (just because the premise is false does not imply the consequent is false). But you already know that you need $n(n+1)^2$ to divide $n!$; this is equivalent to $(n+1)^2$ dividing $(n-1)!$. If $n+1$ is prime, then since all factors of $(n-1)!$ are smaller than $n$, then $n+1$ cannot divide $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be an odd positive integer $\ge 15$. Plainly, there are infinitely many such numbers.

Set $n=4a-1$, so that $(n+1)^2=16a^2$

$a\ge 15 \Rightarrow n \ge 59$. Infinitely many $a$ imply infinitely many $n$.

$n!$ is always divisible by $n$. Also $2,8 <n \Rightarrow 16\mid n!$. Finally, $a,2a<n$ means $2a^2 \mid n!$

In sum $n(16a^2)\mid n! \Rightarrow n(n+1)^2 \mid n!$, so there are infinitely many $n$ which satisfy the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If $n \equiv 5 \mod 6$ and $n \ge 11$ then

$n! = 1*2*3*…*\dfrac{n+1}{3}*…*\dfrac{n+1}{2}*…*n$

Combining the explicit terms gives the required polynomial.